# Laravel validation: How to validate a field with rules if some condition is true

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my code:

```php
$rules = [
    'shape' => ['required', 'in:cubic,rounded'],
    'height' => ['required', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'length' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'width' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'diameter' => ['required_if:shape,rounded', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
]
```

My need is when shape is cubic, validation will ignore diameter (even it gives a value 0).
For example: if I post `shape=cubic&height=10&length=10&width=10&diameter=0`, it will returns `The diameter field must be greater than 0`.

For diameter field, I want the rules `['numeric', 'gt:0']` only available when shape is rounded, otherwise there should be no rules like `[]`.

I try to use `required_if` but it's not suit for this case.

Laravel has no rule named `if`, only `required_if` or other `..._if` rules.

Additional:

> Sorry, I didn't make the requirements clear. The fact is that these rules I will use for excel import, so there will be the field `diameter` anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make your example work just use:

```
$rules = [
'shape' => ['required', 'in:cubic,rounded'],
'height' => ['required', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
'length' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
'width' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
'diameter' => ['exclude_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
]
```

to add a little bit of context:

The required_if, will validate your input if present that is why your example failed but if it was:

```
shape=cubic&height=10&length=10&width=10
```

this would have succeeded.

So if your parameters are always present the exclude_if is what you need

Comment: The truth is that these are the rules I'll be using for the excel import, so there will be a field for diameter anyway

Comment: and so exclude_if works well, right?

Comment: I haven't used this rule, but I just read the official documentation and it should fit my needs, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rule in Laravel

```
php artisan make:rule
```

by creating a custom rule you are free to write any kind of validation that you want.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just want to make sure if there's any easier way to do it.

Comment: Rules are customized thing, so it need work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present) in validation

```
$rules = [
    'shape' => ['required', 'in:cubic,rounded'],
    'height' => ['required', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'length' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'width' => ['required_if:shape,cubic', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
    'diameter' => ['sometimes', 'required_if:shape,rounded', 'numeric', 'gt:0'],
];
```